# Magento 2 : How to Remove Container Div From CMS Page

Tags: magento-2.1, cms, cms-pages, containers

How to remove container block from cms page for particular layout. I have created new layout and apply on cms page but not able to customize it.

Below my custom layout code:

> app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/moza/Magento_Theme

**layouts.xml**

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="fullpage">
        <label translate="true">Full Page Layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

> app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/moza/Magento_Theme/page_layout

**fullpagelayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
</layout>
```

It is possible to set block outside the main container?

Comment: can you tell me what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Dhiren check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Check Magento  documentation guide on layout
 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

**Remove container block from cms page**

```
<referenceBlock name="your_block_name" remove="1"/>
```

**You can create  custom layout**

> app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/moza/Magento_Theme

**layouts.xml**

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="fullpage">
        <label translate="true">Full Page</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

`app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/moza/Magento_Theme/page_layout`

> filename should be layout id `fullpage.xml`

**fullpage.xml**

> it may be update any layout `1column` or `empty` or `2column-left` or `2column-right` Just replace `<update handle=”empty”/>` with the layout you wish to use, e.g `<update handle=”3columns”/>`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" after="-" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

**if you want to further customize/override these layout `1column.xml` or `empty.xml` or `2column-left` or `2column-right.xml` or `3column.xml`**

copy from `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/page-layout/empty.xml`.

to

`app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/moza/Magento_Theme/page_layout`

copy from

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page-layout/`1column.xml`,`2column-left`,`2column-right.xml`,`3column.xml` .

to

`app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/moza/Magento_Theme/page_layout`

**Yes you can  set block outside the main container check following path**

`app/design/frontend/CleverSoft/moza/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Let's assume this is your block

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your_block_name" template="vendor_modulename::template.phtml"/>
```

*Here's how you set your block after main container*

```
<move element="your_block_name" destination="page.wrapper" after="main.content"/>
```